# В чём различия Pretty Url?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, url, маршрутизация

Есть два вида pretty url:

*controller/action/?par1=value1&par2=value2*

и

*controller/action/par1/value1/par2/value2*

подскажите пожалуйста в чём критические различия, плюсы и минусы каждого.
Мне известно что Zend framework использует второй вид pretty url, а yii2 первый.
Очень интересно почему они пришли именно к такому виду и правильное ли это решение.

Comment: Знаете, местные обычаи порицают отсылки в гуглы и прочие яндексы за ответами. Однако, ваш вопрос порождает встречный - вы уже пробовали найти ответ на свой вопрос самостоятельно?  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Семантический_URL https://aweb.ua/advices/2013-03-21

Comment: А потом люди упорно делают ЧПУ на Yii2...

Comment: И тут отвечу, что оба этих урла ни разу не pretty url